# 2 Points, 3 points, 4 points Numerical Differentiation (forward)

Tags: numerical-methods

http://www.shodor.org/cserd/Resources/Algorithms/NumericalDifferentiation/

How did they get the three points
$$y'(x)=\frac{y(x+h)-y(x-h)}{2h}$$
to
$$y'(x)=\frac{-3y(x)+4y(x+h)-y(x+2h)}{2h}$$

Where does the $-3y + 4y$ come from? It does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

It arises as follows (based on the method discussed [in the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1500202/three-point-numerical-differentiation):

$$ y(x+h) \approx y(x) + hy'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}y''(x)$$
$$y(x+2h) \approx y(x) + 2hy'(x) + 2h^2y''(x)$$

To cancel the $y''$ terms, we take

$$4y(x+h) - y(x+2h) \approx 3y(x) + 2hy'(x)$$
The advantage of canceling these terms is that it gives us a better estimate -- the error here is now on the order of $h^3$, since we've canceled the $h^2$ terms.

Thus we get $$-3y(x) + 4y(x+h)-y(x+2h) \approx 2hy'(x)$$
So $$y'(x) \approx \frac{-3y(x) + 4y(x+h)-y(x+2h)}{2h}$$ with error on the order of $\frac{h^3}{h}=h^2$.